# Dropdown created using jquery not opening in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, dynamic, dropdown, kendo-dropdown

I have created a dynamic dropdown list using jquery. Refer the below code

```
 CreateDropDown: function (e, grid, defaultvalue) {
    var field = $("#" + grid).data("kendoGrid").columns[e.index()].field;
    $("#" + field).hide();
     var kendoddl = $("<input id='DDL'  />");
     e.append(kendoddl);       
     $("#DDL").find('select').append( $("#DDL").kendoDropDownList({
         dataTextField: 'LevelName',
         dataValueField: 'Levelvalue',
         index: 0,
         change: LocalSetup.LevelOnSelect,
         dataSource: {
             transport: {
                 read: {
                     url: "/ONT/TYK/GetDropDowndata"
                 }
             },
             serverFiltering: true
         },
     })
    );
    var value = LocalSetup.checkLevelValue(defaultvalue);
    var dropdownlist = $("#DDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.value(value);
},
```

The code works fine when viewed from IE. But the issue occurs in Chrome. The dropdown does not open and display the options. Please suggest.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No. There aren't any.